# Best way to set a cookie with a script then redirect?

Tags: php, cookies, redirect

I need to set a tracking cookie from a 3rd party before redirecting to another domain.

The 3rd party provided this script.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var ssa = '8g38f7g5yg8H84hh5';
    var ssaUrl = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') +      'pixel.trackingdomain.com/iap/' + ssa;
    new Image().src=ssaUrl;
</script>
```

What would be the best/fastest way to do this?

Comment: Do you use any JavaScript library? Also, New Image() is HTML5 Constructor (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement#Example). That may not work for all the browser! I would suggest to use <img /> HTML Tag to do pixel tracking

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to wait until the tracking request has completed, use the `onload` event to defer redirection:

```
var ssa = '8g38f7g5yg8H84hh5';
var ssaUrl = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') +
              'pixel.trackingdomain.com/iap/' + ssa;
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    document.location.href = "http://redirect.to.somewhere/";
};
img.src=ssaUrl;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jon. It was kind of you to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then you can use below mentioned code.

```
var ssa = "8g38f7g5yg8H84hh5";
var ssaUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/pixel.trackingdomain.com/iap/" + ssa;
var tracker = $("<img/>").attr({ src: ssaUrl }).bind("load", function (event) {
        window.location.href = "http://redirect.to.somewhere/";
    }).appendTo("body");
```